# Connection failure to WMS/WMTS or WFS

Tags: qgis, connection, ows

Why can't I connect to any of the Web Map Services (WMS/WMTS/WFS) in QGIS?

I don't think its a problem with the servers I'm using, but more about QGIS not being connected to the internet maybe.

The pop-up error is:

> Host could not be found.

[image]

[image]

Examples of servers I am using:

1. (WFS) https://wxs.ign.fr/choisirgeoportail/geoportail/wfs?
2. (WMS/WMTS) https://wxs.ign.fr/choisirgeoportail/geoportail/wmts? SERVICE=WMTS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities
3. (WMS/WMTS) https://portal.opentopography.org/dataCatalog?listAll=true&group=global

Version: QGIS Desktop 3.10.2

Comment: At least the second one works for me after bypassing the error message about certificate error. The URL to connect is `https://wxs.ign.fr/choisirgeoportail/geoportail/wmts?service=WMTS&request=GetCapabilities` and I tested with orthophoto layer.

Comment: @user30184 On my end I can't connect to any server, the hosts can't be found. 
Is there an option I should enable before trying to connect to a web map service?

Comment: Do you have a proxy server in your Network?

Comment: @user30184 no, I'm not using a proxy. Should I?

Comment: I do not know your network. If you are in a company network and external http traffic must go through a proxy server then yes, you must use proxy with QGIS as well.

Comment: I can confirm: I was able to connect to the WMS/WMTS under the URL @user30184 provided. As well, I was able to connect to the WFS under the URL provided by Pod

Answer (score 1):

I try to use the first link and it works like this:

```
https://wxs.ign.fr/choisirgeoportail/geoportail/wfs
```

The second link is necessary to add ? between wmts and SERVICE

```
https://wxs.ign.fr/choisirgeoportail/geoportail/wmts?SERVICE=WMTS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities
```

Finally the last link does not have a wms service, but I found a few on the page, and I found this link: https://www.gmrt.org/services/

to visualize the service, you have to do the next steps:

1. Right-click on WMS/WMTS on the navigation pane and click in new Connection.

[image]

2. Enter the name of the Connection, the URL of the service, and click in Accept.

[image]

3. Finally, you can select in the navigation pane and choose the service that you want to visualize.

[image]

Example of the third link:

[image]

Comment: Hi Jhon, my problem starts in your 3rd image. On my end it doesn't connect to any of the navigation services. Instead I have "Error al descargar posibilidades"